# Python - Duplicate Elements in Nested List

Tags: python, matrix, nested-lists

I have a nested list like:

**[ [5] , [10] ]**

How can I duplicate each element in the list to obtain:

**[ [5,5] , [10,10] ]**

In reality it could be that each element repeats "n" number of times:

**[ [5,5,5] , [10,10,10] ]**

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far (forming a [mcve]), example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def repeat_n(lst, n):
    return [elem * n for elem in lst]

>>> repeat_n([[5], [10]], 3)
[[5, 5, 5], [10, 10, 10]]
```